# Place a method in which class

Tags: php, oop, class-method

I have a question that's more of a best practice rather that an actual problem.

Supposed I'm building a projects app and each project would have multiple tasks that need to be completed.

So the projects class:

```
class Project {
    public $id;
    public $name;

    // Get tasks of this project
    public function getTasks() {
            // some logic to get tasks of this project
    }

    // Should a method for adding task go here
    public function addTask() {
           // some logic going here
    }
}
```

And the tasks class:

```
class Task {
     public $id;
     public $name;

     // Should a method for adding task go here
     public function add_task($project_id) {
          // The task class here needs to know the project_id
          // to continue with the logic
     }
}
```

As you can tell, any task always belongs to a certain project.

Adding a task should be considered a method for tasks or because any task always belongs to a project, it should part of the project class?? Is there a more correct one? So a task is a task and at the same time it's owned by a project

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. So there is no fixed right or wrong. But if a `Task` always belongs to a `Project`, I think it is more predictable to only have the `addTask` method on `Project`.

Comment: So project should act like the manager of the tasks. It doesn't make sense for the task to manage itself, right?

Comment: I think so. But there are different model in do things. I think it all come down to how intuitive it is to maintain your codebase. That's why its opinion-based.

Comment: In [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent), a model class always maintain its own table. So doing `Task` in Eloquent would means using `$task = new Task()` and then `$task->save()`.

Comment: I think a large majority would say the container adding the content is more intuitive than the content adding itself to the container. Im no OOP expert but for your example, I personally would have an array of tasks as an attribute of Project class, therefore the function "addTask"  would make 1000x more sense to be in the Project class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single Responsibility Principle

> A class should have one and only one reason to change, meaning that a
>   class should have only one job.

If Project class's responsibility is to manage Tasks, `addTask` should be a Project method.

Consider the possibility of adding `addTask` method to Tasks. This would violate the Single Responsibility for the Tasks class. Task would then represent a task, ***plus*** it would then have the responsibility of adding itself to some collection of tasks.

Comment: Single Responsibility Principle is very opiniated. You can say Project has 1 responsibility to manage the projects - 1 responsibility, Person X could say getting tasks and adding tasks  are 2 different responsibilities. From your view you are correct, from X point of view he is correct

Comment: @suspectus So project should act like the manager of the tasks. It doesn't make sense for the task to manage itself, right?

Comment: @user2693928 that's why it's confusing me as well! No matter what, I find my self violating this rule a lot but I guess in this case since tasks are mainly "owned" by a project, it makes perfect sense to be managed by a project. They are just in a different table because there are many so can't just fit in a column in the project class. Supposed there was only 1 task per project and it was as a column in the projects table, it would be perfectly managed by the project. Now I guess it's the same but in a separate table

Comment: @MichaelSamuel correct. If Project class is to manage tasks, Project must provide the mechanism to add a task to Project's collection. classes should be singular in purpose. The Task class should have no idea about how it is managed.

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented programming allows us to keep many classes that cater to more specific objects, and ultimately allow us to guarantee certain structure or behavior within our application.

With that in mind you should remember that your objects can be created with constructors with optional parameters. Meaning we can create both our project and tasks, and know that they adhere to certain conditions.

Consider instead, the following code:

```
class Project {
    public $id = 0;
    public $name = '';
    public $tasks = [];

    // Creates a new class, project, with the specified parameters.
    __construct($i = 0, $n = "", $t = []) {
      $id = $i;
      $name = $n;
      $tasks = $t;
    }

    // Get tasks of this project
    public function getTasks() {
            return $tasks;
    }

    // A function to create a new task and assign it to our tracked list of takss
    public function addTask($i, $n) {
           array_push($tasks, new Task($i, $n);
    }
}


class Task {
     public $id;
     public $name;

     // Creates a new class, tasks, with the specified parameters.
    __construct($i = 0, $n = "") {
      $id = $i;
      $name = $n;
    }
}
```

Then, elsewhere on your page or part of your application, you can simply call.

```
$project = new Project(1, "The First Project", []);
$project.addTask(1, "My first task");
$project.addTask(2, "My second task");
var_dump($project.getTasks());
// You will see an array of your two tasks.
```

Comment: Based on the above, you assume that task(s) should be managed by the project rather than by itself as it's owned by a project actually? You just put stuff into constructors i see

Comment: That's not at all what I've said, or what I've answered. A task should manage a task. However, it shouldn't have it's own ADD Task function, as we know a task has been added, if it exists. 

Your requirement was that tasks must have a project, therefore it makes sense to create them from within the project they are assigned. 

If you wished, you could place the project ID, into the task also to keep an easy log as to what belong where.

Comment: So you mean that getting the tasks should be from the tasks table and to be injected into the project constructor while adding a new task should be from the project?

Comment: Not quite. A task is responsible for a task. Not for tasks. Notice the plurality. So add a new task from the project, and get a list of tasks from the project also. However, if the task had maybe a status to it that you updated based on some condition, then that can be handled within the task itself. That way, per project, you can iterate through the tasks in its array, and call those tasks to perform a function.